# Get the average of numbers in an array which is the values of an hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, average

in a Ruby program I have an hash which has normal strings as keys and the values are array of numbers:

```
hash_1 = {"Luke"=> [2,3,4], "Mark"=>[3,5], "Jack"=>[2]}
```

And what I'm looking for is to have as result the same hash with the values that become the average of the numbers inside the arrays:

```
{"Luke"=> 3, "Mark"=>4, "Jack"=>2}
```

One way to make it to work can be to create a new empty hash_2, loop over hash_1 and within the block assign the keys to hash_2 and the average of the numbers as values.

```
hash_2 = {}

hash_1.each do |key, value|
  hash_2[key] = value.sum / value.count
end

hash_2 = {"Luke"=> 3, "Mark"=>4, "Jack"=>2}
```

Is there a better way I could do this, for instance without having to create a new hash?

Comment: You may want to throw in a .to_f in the calculation, since the average of a bunch of integers is often not an integer.

Comment: I didn't know John had the nickname "Jack". And where's Matthew, by the way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hash_1 = {"Luke"=> [2,3,4], "Mark"=>[3,5], "Jack"=>[2]}
```

You don't need another hash for the given below code.

```
p hash_1.transform_values!{|x| x.sum/x.count}
```

Result

```
{"Luke"=>3, "Mark"=>4, "Jack"=>2}
```

Comment: @Виктор I edited above. Please look at the answer again. It doesn't return the new hash.

Comment: If I adopt this way then I need to store the result of hash_1.transform_values{|x| x.sum/x.count} into a new hash because I need the data to be persistent.

Comment: I am confused as to whether you want to mutate the original hash or not. Do you want to? If you want to do that, then this is the way.

Comment: @Emanuele I have changed my answer a bit, Now I believe it suits your need exactly. I used `transform_values!`, this operate on original hash.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to make the change on the original hash and yes by adding the exclamation mark your answer perfectly solves the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
def avg(arr)
  return nil if arr.empty?
  arr.sum.fdiv(arr.size)
end
```

```
h = { "Matthew"=>[2], "Mark"=>[3,6], "Luke"=>[2,3,4], "Jack"=>[] }
```

```
h.transform_values { |v| avg(v) }
  #=> {"Matthew"=>2.0, "Mark"=>4.5, "Luke"=>3.0, "Jack"=>nil}
```

Comment: Fdiv is the new thing for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Виктор
OK. How about this:

```
hash_1 = {"Luke"=> [2,3,4], "Mark"=>[3,5], "Jack"=>[2], "Bobby"=>[]}

hash_2 = hash_1.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |acc, (k, v)|
  v.size > 0 ? acc[k] = v.sum / v.size : acc[k] = 0 
  acc
end

p hash_2
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is different than the one that use `transform_values!` because return a new Hash object.

```
hash_1.map { |k,v| [k, v.sum / v.size] }.to_h
```